# How to specify authentication database and target database separately on mongodb connection uri?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.4

I am using this connection uri to connect to mongodb: `mongodb://user:password@localhost/admin`. It will use `admin` as bot authentication and target database. How can I make the uri to use `admin` as authentication but allow me to connect to a different database? Please see below command as an example:

`mongo --host localhost -u user -p password --authentication admin test`

the above command will use `admin` as the authentcation database but connect to `test` database. how can I do the same thing on uri?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes.. Easily!

```
mongo "mongodb://test:testpwd@localhost/test?authSource=admin"
MongoDB shell version v3.4.6
connecting to: mongodb://test:testpwd@localhost/test?authSource=admin
MongoDB server version: 3.4.6
MongoDB> db
test
MongoDB>
```

You put your destination DB at end of "base" string and add authentication db to parameter authSource

Comment: Yep, this is exactly what i am looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Ref:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#connections-connection-options

You will need to use below format and do not need to use admin database.

mongodb://user:password@localhost/test?authSource=admin

> /database Optional. The name of the database to authenticate if the
>   connection string includes authentication credentials in the form of
>   username:password@. If /database is not specified and the connection
>   string includes credentials, the driver will authenticate to the admin
>   database.

Make sure you have a user in `test` database. See section 6 of this document.

[Enable Auth](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/)

**Create additional users as needed for your deployment.**

> The database where you create the user (in this example, test) is that
>   user’s authentication database. Although the user would authenticate
>   to this database, the user can have roles in other databases; i.e. the
>   user’s authentication database does not limit the user’s privileges.

```
use test
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myTester",
    pwd: "xyz123",
    roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "test" },
             { role: "read", db: "reporting" } ]
  }
)
```

Comment: I have tried this uri but it doesn't work. Because it tries to use `test` as the authentication database which is not correct. I need to use `admin` as authentication database and connect to `test` database.

Comment: Modified answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I don't want to change the user role on the database instance. Is there any solution not to make any change on the instance?

Comment: That is how it is designed by MongoDB.

Comment: Does this mean I can't achieve this by mongo uri?

Comment: I do not know for sure if there is any workaround.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide you can update your answer by adding ?authSource=admin at the end of the URI string